# How to make collectionViewCell have a different width content

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

i create a tab menu using collectionViewCell but, i have 5 cell menu. but the name in cell got truncate, i want if there is a long name label. the container view in collectionViewCell should grow.

[image: truncate label]

i try to use the collectionViewFlowLayout estimatedItemSize, but the result is. the cell become ugly not like before

[image: estimatedItemSize]

How to make the collectionViewCell grow size but maintain full width.

this is my setup for my collectionViewCell

```
private let padding: CGFloat = 8

override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }
    
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

private func configure() {
        addSubview(selectionView)
        selectionView.addSubview(titleLabel)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            selectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: padding),
            selectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 4),
            selectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -4),
            selectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -padding),

            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: selectionView.topAnchor, constant: padding),
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: selectionView.leadingAnchor, constant: 4),
            titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: selectionView.trailingAnchor, constant: -4),
            titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: selectionView.bottomAnchor, constant: -padding)
        ])
    }
```

and this is my setup for my collectionView

```
private func setupCollectionView() {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(TabCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: TabCollectionViewCell.cellID)

        [notificationLabel, collectionView].forEach { view in
            guard let view = view else { return }
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addSubview(view)
        }

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            notificationLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 8),
            notificationLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
            notificationLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),

            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: notificationLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -8)
        ])

    }

extension HeaderCollectionView: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width / CGFloat(items.count), height: collectionView.bounds.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

}
```

Comment: So, you want a certain minimum width, but for cells that need to be larger, you want it to grow with the text? Try adding a `selectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: minWidth)`.

Comment: yes that's right @Rob i want the cell grow by the text. I try your method but still not working. it still like the second one,

Comment: Seems like it would be a lot simpler to put the 5 buttons in a `UIStackView` instead of using a `UICollectionView`.

Comment: ferryawaijayanto - Yes, my `widthAnchor` technique (with `.automaticSize`, but no `sizeForItemAt`) will achieve the second the second. I didn’t know what you meant by “grow but maintain will width”. I now understand what you’re trying to achieve. And HangarRash is 100% right, that a stack view is the right solution, rather than contorting yourself with collection view. You should only use collection view if you need scrolling behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a String extension method that will calculate the width of the string and after that use that in your delegate method:

Step 1: Calculate the string width

```
extension String {
    func getStringwidth(height: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], context: nil)
        return boundingBox.width
    }
}
```

Step 3: Calculate the max width

```
func calculateMaxWidth()-> CGFloat {
        // my Data shource array Data
        var allSize: [CGFloat] = []
        arrayData.forEach{
            allSize.append($0.widthWithConstrainedHeight(height: 30,
                                                         font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)))
        }
        return allSize.max() ?? 0.0
        
    }
```

Step 2: Call the max from viewdidLoad

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.estimatedItemSize =  CGSize(width: calculateMaxWidth(), height: 30)
```

Adjust based on your requirement.

Output:
[image]

Comment: thank you for your help, i try your method. it's still not working, i think it makes easier if use stackView like @HangarRash said

Comment: @ferryawijayanto That is another solution.  I update my answer and try that. It is working for me.